# Displaying element behind other with z-index doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I created this fiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AVxbd/

I have a menu (`#container`), with some links (`#text1`, `#text2`). I made a `#highlighter` element to highlight the link of the page the person is on a specific moment. The HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="highlighter"></div>
    <div id="text1">Text 1</div><div id="text2">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```js
$('#highlighter')
    .offset($('#text1').offset())
    .width($('#text1').width()
);

$('#text1, #text2').click(function(){
    $('#highlighter').animate({
        top: $(this).offset().top,
        left: $(this).offset().left,
        width: $(this).width() + "px"
    },300);
});
```

The problem is that the `#highlighter` element is displayed *over* the `#text1` and `#text2` elements. That's not what I want!

I tried to solve this with the z-index:

```css
#container {     z-index: 1; }
#highlighter {   z-index: 2; }
#text1, #text2 { z-index: 3; }
```

However, that doesn't work, as you can see in the fiddle.

How can I get this to work? I want to let it look like the `#text1` and `#text2` element have an orange background, but because I want the highlighter to animate in width and position, I can't just give those elements a background themselves.

Comment: The `+ "px" ` is not explicitly needed as you didn't use it for top and left either. I think the z-index is also redundant, because the highlighter element is the first inside the container, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVxbd/7/ (i moved the highlighter to the end, so it's the last element)

Comment: @Imperative yeah, I just added them to be sure _that_ wasn't the problem. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `#text1, #text2`

http://jsfiddle.net/AVxbd/2/

z-index applies only to positioned elements.

Comment: `+1` and a link to specification is always useful [CSS/Properties/z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

Answer (score 2):

```
#text1, #text2 {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 30px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 3;
*position:relative;*
```

}

Add **position** to this class. Z-index does not work if position is not defined.

[For details on position and z-index, click here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index)

Comment: position is always defined but by default it is 'static'

Comment: Just wanted to make you aware of a [helpful question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives) regarding linking to w3schools

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `position:relative;` for #text1 and #text2

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AVxbd/5/)